# Cyclic (sub)groups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I have two questions that are confusing me.

Why is the cyclic group generated by $g$ the smallest subgroup containing $g$?

If $g$ generates an infinite subgroup, why is it called cyclic? I mean, there is no power $m\gt 0$ so that $g^m=e$, the identity, so $g$ does not cycle.

---

Not sure that this reasoning answers the first question but here it is: if $g$ generates a subgroup $G$, then $e,g,g^{-1}$ are all in $G$, now we add elements in pairs $g^2,(g^2)^{-1},\dots$. This is the smallest subgroup containing $g$ for if another subgroup contains $g$, it must contain another element $f$ and so is larger than the former group.

Comment: For the first one, I think a more set-theoretic argument works better (this might just be my taste, though). As for the second one, I believe it is called cyclic because every element in $G$ can be written as $g^n$ for some $n\in \Bbb Z$. This is only a guess, so I hope someone else who knows better can properly answer the second question.

Comment: For the second question: $m=0 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Leo That works only if the group is trivial $\{e\}$ (this is finite). $\{e\}$ has order $1$ not $0$.

Comment: @saadtaame: $g^0=e$ for every $g\in G$ by definition.

Comment: @StefanH. That's trivial. There is no positive power though.

Comment: @saadtame I thought this was a convention: $g^0=e$. Hence $e \in \langle g \rangle$

Comment: @Leo $0$ is not the order of $<g>$ if it's not trivial

Comment: Oh there has been an edit... Well of course there is no $m > 0$ for which $g^m=0$ if g generates an infinite subgroup. That would mean $g^{m+1}=g$, and that would mean $\langle g \rangle$ is finite...

Comment: For the first question. The usual procedure is: Let $G=\{g^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$ and let $\langle g\rangle$ denote the subgroup generated by $g$. (1) Show that $G\subseteq H$ for each subgroup $H$ containing $g$. This shows $G\subseteq\langle g\rangle$. (2) Show that $G$ itself is a group containing $g$. This shows $\langle g\rangle\subseteq G$.

Comment: @saadtame I don't think we understand each other: Are you saying that if $G$ is not trivial $g^0 \neq e$? Because I thought it was just convention to say $g^0 =e$. It's a sensible convention $e=g^1 *g^{-1}=g^{1+(-1)}=g^{0}$.

Comment: Your second point is a good question! I do not have an answer, although I suspect it is because for finite cyclic groups there is a single element which generates the group, so you generalise in the natural way to get the infinite cyclic group. So it is just a name, and it doesn't cycle per-se.

Comment: I have no doubt that @user1729: is correct: amongst finite groups the cyclic groups are precisely those generated by a single element, and it’s convenient to extend the term *cyclic* to cover the one infinite group generated by a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to summarize my answer, cause we have been debating a lot in the comment section and it has got a little blurry.

So first let's define $\langle g \rangle$. In my algebra course it's defined as

$\langle g \rangle=\lbrace g^s | s \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace $.

A cyclic group is defined as a group $G,*$ for which there exists $g \in G$ such that  $\langle g \rangle $. This is equivalent with the wikipedia definition: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group

Now for the first question: Suppose there exists a subgroup $H$ which contains $g$. We now have to prove that $\langle g \rangle \subset H$. No problem: since $H $is a group, all $g^s$ with $s \in \mathbb{Z}$ are in $H$. Therefore $\langle g \rangle \subset H$.

For the second question: It seems to me that the existence of $m>0$ such that $g^m$=e is not a necessary condition to prove that $\langle g \rangle$ is cyclic. If you take as convention/notation that $g^0=e$, you can easily see that $\langle g \rangle$ is a group. And suppose there would be an $m>0$ such that $g^m=0$. Then $g^{m+1}=g$ and thus $g$ cannot generate a infinite group. That's just a plain contradiction with the fact that $g$ does generate a infinite group.

Comment: The OP's second question is just about the choice of the term "cyclic" in the infinite case.  She's not denying the existence of infinite cyclic groups but rather wondering why they're called cyclic given that there is no periodicity ("cycling") occurring in the powers of the generator.  (I don't know a good answer to this.  It seems that the terminology got used because of the analogy with the finite case.)